# VS project Error: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, stylecop

When I try to open a legacy Visual Studio solution, I get this error for all its projects (so they fail loading): **‘The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.’**. The line on the project file that is causing the error seems to be this one: `<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />`. How can I install StyleCop so its files go to that folder? I have tried to install it on my machine both as a Nuget package and as a VS extension but none of these options put the files in that path. I have not found the MSI installer itself, only the Nuget option. One constraint I have is that I need to keep the project files as they are. I am using VS 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the installer [here](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/629688), I used it, it added the missing folder and this solved the issue. When installing it is important to make sure the MSBUILD option in the installer window is selected.

Comment: your solution is out of date. The stylecop link is closed.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the installer, but if you go into the project file (.csproj) and comment out the line

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />
```

you should be able to load the project.